# database in jtable

Tags: java, database, swing, jtable, netbeans-7

im am try to fetch data from MS Access database into a JTable.When i run this code snippet in console its working fine but when i do it on a button event in netbeans its not showing any thing.I am using following code and my table name is table1.

```
     private void jButton11ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    Vector columnNames = new Vector();
    Vector data = new Vector();

    try {
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:rrr");
    String sql = "Select * from client";
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql );
    ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
    int columns = md.getColumnCount();
    for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
      columnNames.addElement( md.getColumnName(i) );
    }
    while (rs.next()) {
    Vector row = new Vector(columns);
    for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++){
      row.addElement( rs.getObject(i) );
    }
    data.addElement( row );
    }
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
   System.out.println(e);
    }
    JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
    TableColumn col;
    for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
    col = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
     col.setMaxWidth(250);
    }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need a top level window, which should be doable with the Netbeans framework (which I guess you're using).

Then add the table and the button to that window and register an `Action` or `ActionListener` to the button. In that action you spawn a new worker thread (e.g. `SwingWorker`), load the date inside that thread and update the table's model when finished.

Comment: thank @Thomas but im new to swing can u help me out with a code snippet for above..

Comment: @prakash_d22 have a look at the Swing tutorials at the oracle site. You should get a basic sence of how Swing works.

Answer (score 1):

In your current solution, you make a new `JTable` instance when the button is pressed. However, that `JTable` is not added to any component, so once your `actionPerformed` method returns, the reference to the `JTable` is lost and it will not show.

```
JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
TableColumn col;
for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
  col = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
   col.setMaxWidth(250);
}
//here is a missing statement, like panel.add( table );
```

If you already have an existing table, it might be better to update the model of that existing table instead of creating a new one, as Thomas already suggested. Also, consider constructing the table model on another thread then the EDT by using a `SwingWorker`. This avoids a blocked UI while the database is queried and the table constructed. Example usages of the `SwingWorker` can be found in the [Swing Concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: Code snippets (actually, full working examples) can be found in the tutorial to which I linked